# In Unity 5.0, the audio for android have lag, any way to reduce the lag?

Tags: android, audio, unity-game-engine

In my game, I need to have shoot, hit, blast sound effect, and they are all less than 1 seconds. However, when the sound plays, it have lag on some specific devices.

HTC One M8: 0.4s lag 
Samsung Galaxy S6: 0.4s lag 
Samsung Galaxy S3: 0.4s lag 
Samsung Galaxy Tab 3: no lag 
iPad Air: no lag

Any idea how to solve the problem?

I already tried the following:

AudioSettings, best latency; 
All audio data are wav; 
All audio data are imported and compressed as PCM; 
All audio data are "decompress on load"; 
AudioSources bypass all the effects; 
There is a Android latency plugin, seems not working on new Unity, there is no sound at all; 
There is another audio plugin, which have the same problem.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have an s3 and experience no lag with audio. Even with lots audio files playing and overlapping.

This is leading me to believe something else is causing lag which results in your audio doing this.

Theres nothing posted here with how you went about setting this up or what other logic is happening when the audio file gets Play()'d

Ive had similar effects on my s3 when using coroutines, but i eventually found it was my wrong doing, specifically with the coroutine.

Hope this is helpful in anyway for you and good luck!

Comment: This is a test project for sound delay test, and there is only one button and an AudioSource in the scene, which contains a single AudioClip, a wav file imported as PCM. What I did is click the button, and play the AudioSource. There are no other gameobjects in the scene.